# Why are there multiple ttf files for a font?

Tags: fonts

I don't know how fonts work. For me, I just like Dejavu font, so I download it from the website. But when I unzip the file, there're so many ttf files. do I need to go through them one by one to install them?  And what is the font config folder for? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: IIRC, right-click → Install should also work when multiple files are selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why are there multiple ttf files for a font?

Your font files list is a **Font Family** called **DejaVu**.

A single font file contains only one font with one style (one of normal/oblique/italic) and one weight (one of normal/bold)

You don't need to install them all only the ones you plan to use.

> The full DejaVu fonts family contains following styles:
>
> - Sans: Book, Bold, Oblique, Bold Oblique, Condensed, Condensed Bold, Condensed Oblique and Condensed Bold Oblique, Extralight
> - Serif: Book, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic, Condensed, Condensed Bold, Condensed Italic and Condensed Bold Italic
> - Mono: Book, Bold, Oblique, Bold Oblique

Source [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page)

---

#### Do I need to go through them one by one to install them?

You can install multiple fonts at the the time by selecting them, then right click and select "Install".

[image]

---

#### What is the font config folder for?

This folder contains configuration files for `Fontconfig`.

See [Fontconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig) for more information.

Comment: Why do we need different font sizes and styles (bold, italic, regular) for a font? I installed just one of them and was able to make it bold, or italic, or increase the size in Word.

Comment: @User10482 You will get better font rendering if you have specific fonts available for each style.

Comment: I did not expect a reply after 5 years! I see. So it's better to have original fonts drawn for the given style rather than software like Word process it. Also, I have numbers in front of the font name (ex:"lmroman9-bold" or "lmroman12-regular"). What would the number mean in this context?